# Microsoft SQL Server data-tier application. Can you override procedure from reference dacpac

Tags: sql-server, reference, overriding, dacpac

I have Microsoft SQL Server data-tier application with reference to other data-tier application as a `.dacpac`.

I would like to override a procedure from reference `.dacpac` with new code in a current `.dacpac`.

I have universal code `.dacpac` and customer specific `.dacpac` with reference to universal one. I would like to make a placeholder stored procedure in universal `.dacpac` and then in customer specific rewrite it. I need a way to make universal `.dacpac` procedure run a procedure which is customer specific.

Putting the new code for the procedure with the same name in new `.dacpac` is causing a build error.